# Scala - While loop with an Iterator and also with a state checker

Tags: scala, while-loop, iterator

First of all, I'm new to Scala. I have the following (working) Scala method(s) that has to wait up to 15 sec for a record to be completed. Usually, after 7 seconds, the record becomes complete. So, I put an Iterator that goes to maximum 15 seconds, if the record is complete it stops (I didn't know how to stop the iteration other than with drop). If it isn't completed, it should sleep 1 sec. The problem is that I have to give as a parameter, the method checkIfRecordIsComplete because I might use this wait method with other Boolean functions. How can I use wait method with... let's say checkIfOtherIsComplete? Thanks!

```
def checkIfRecordIsComplete(record: Record) = {
    println("record.state="+record.state)
    if(record.state.contains(Constants.RecordStatusComplete))
      true
    else
      false
}

def checkIfOtherIsComplete(other: Other) = {
    println("other.state="+other.state)
    if(other.state.contains(Constants.OtherStatusComplete))
      true
    else
      false
}

def wait(recordId: RecordId, maxW: Int): Unit = {
    val it = Iterator.iterate(1){_+1}.take(maxW)
    while(it.hasNext) {
      val recordList = getRecord(recordId)
      recordList.records.foreach {
        record => {
          if(!checkIfRecordIsComplete(record)){
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            it.next()
          }
          else
            it.drop(maxW)
        }
      }
    }
}

........................
wait(recordId, 15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a type that provides a common functionality for `Record` and `Other`. In this case, that might be a `trait` implemented by both. For example:

```
trait Completable {

  def isComplete: Boolean

}
```

Now, both `Record` and `Other` should extend it:

```
trait Record extends Completable {

  // ...

  override def isComplete: Boolean = this.state.contains(Constants.RecordStatusComplete)

}

trait Other extends Completable {

  // ...

  override def isComplete: Boolean = this.state.contains(Constants.OtherStatusComplete)

}
```

The `wait` function should be slightly changed in order to have access to a sequence (list) of `Completable`s. In fact, since the check logic is now inside `Record` and `Other`, there is no more need to have dedicated functions like `checkIfOtherIsComplete`:

```
// returns the Completable to be checked for completion.
// replaces the former getRecord
private def getItems(recordId: RecordId): Seq[Completable] = ???

def wait(recordId: RecordId, maxW: Int): Unit = {
  val it = Iterator.iterate(1){_+1}.take(maxW)
  while(it.hasNext) {
    getItems(recordId).foreach{
      item => if (item.isComplete) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        it.next()
      } else {
        it.drop(maxW)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, I doubt a bit about the reliability of the implemented solution to make such checks using this `Iterator` approach. But since it works, it's might be OK for your case. If you are interested, we can continue to discuss it.

*Update*

Another approach to implement the waiting sequence might be to use standard Scala features from `scala.concurrent.*` package.

We can use a `Future` and await for its completion. For example:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

def wait2(recordId: RecordId, maxW: Int): Unit = {
  val waitForAllComplete = Future {
    while(!getItems(recordId).forall(_.isComplete)) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
  Await.ready(waitForAllComplete, Duration(maxW, "second"))
}
```

Now, if the sequence is not complete after `maxW` seconds, there will be a `TimeoutException` thrown. This might be helpful if you need to ensure that for all the items in the list the state is expected and to handle the unexpected situation.

*End-of-update*

Comment: can you please suggest me other solution apart from this Iterator solution? Thanks!!!